# Process a Form Submit with Multiple Submit Buttons in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with multiple submit buttons, and I'd like to capture when any of them are pressed, and perform different JS code for each one.

```
<form id="my-form">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="(Your email)" />
    <button type="submit" value="button-one">Go - One</button>
    <button type="submit" value="button-two">Go - Two</button>
    <button type="submit" value="button-three">Go - Three</button>
</form>
```

Looking at an [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5384732/1636799), I can process *all* of the submit buttons in JS:

```
function processForm(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();

    /* do what you want with the form */

    // You must return false to prevent the default form behavior
    return false;
}

var form = document.getElementById('my-form');
if (form.attachEvent) {
    form.attachEvent("submit", processForm);
} else {
    form.addEventListener("submit", processForm);
}
```

But **how can I discriminate amongst the different submit buttons?**  Is there a way to get the `value` and perform logic from there?

I don't need to have three *submit* buttons, per se... I just need three different buttons in a form to perform three different actions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can attach a custom click handler to all buttons, and that way you can check which button is clicked before submitting the form:

<kbd>**[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/ak4r37y1/)**</kbd>

```
$("#my-form button").click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault()// cancel form submission
    if($(this).attr("value")=="button-one"){
        //do button 1 thing
    }
    // $("#my-form").submit(); if you want to submit the form
});
```

Comment: This works well!  I can remove the `attachEvent` stuff and already have jQuery so I might as well use it. Thanks!

Comment: I hope this helps you , Jsfiddle code is here : http://jsfiddle.net/pragneshkaria/eusyrdmy/2/

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the read-only [`submitter` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent/submitter) of a `SubmitEvent`.

HTML (same as you have):

```html
<form id="my-form">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="(Your email)" />
    <button type="submit" value="button-one">Go - One</button>
    <button type="submit" value="button-two">Go - Two</button>
    <button type="submit" value="button-three">Go - Three</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```js
let form = document.getElementById("my-form");
form.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    alert(event.submitter.value) // shows a different value depending on button pressed
```

From there on, it's easy to use `submitter` as a control flow, e.g.:

```js
let form = document.getElementById("my-form");
form.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    submitter = event.submitter.value
    switch (submitter) {
        case "button-one":
            alert(1)
            break;
        case "button-two":
            alert(2)
            break;
        case "button-three":
            alert(3)
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
function processForm(e) {
if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
/* do what you want with the form */
var submit_type = document.getElementById('my-form').getAttribute("value");
if(submit_type=="button-one"){

}//and so on
// You must return false to prevent the default form behavior
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<form id = "form" onSubmit = {handleSubmit}>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="(Your email)" />
<button type="submit" value="button-one">Go - One</button>
<button type="submit" value="button-two">Go - Two</button>
<button type="submit" value="button-three">Go - Three</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    var ans = document.activeElement['value'];
    console.log(ans);
};
```

Comment: Didn't know about activeElement before. This helped me as I had multiple dynamic forms as well as all input fields in the form were dynamic. Moreover, I had two submit-type buttons. I was using jquery's serializedArray() to get all the values of the form using $("form").submit and reading using $(this). activeElement helped me to get the type of submit button clicked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> But how can I discriminate amongst the different submit buttons? Is there a way to get the value and perform logic from there?

Yes, you can use `querySelector` to grab elements with attributes.

```
document.querySelector('#my-form button[value="button-one"]' )
```

Comment: This allows you to target the individual buttons, but doesn't use logic based on which button submitted the form.