# Javascript log in using REST

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a login using JavaScript which should check the user authentication using a REST service, using a client in java (for testing) it return a string "hej" if it's successful. 
My HTML code:

```
    <div class="login">
        <form method="POST">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" required><br><br>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="UserAction()">
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="load_user.js"></script>
```

And heres my javascript code (load_user.js)

```
var username;
var password;

function UserAction() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/Footballmanagerrestservice/webresources/login", false);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("", User());
  xhttp.send();
  var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
  console.log(response);
  if (response == "hej") {
      var url = "http://localhost:8080/FM3/spil2.jsp";
      $(location).attr('href', url);
}
}

function User(user, pass) {
  username = document.getElementById("username").toString();
  username = document.getElementById("password").toString();
  var UserAndPass = "?username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
return UserAndPass;
}
```

I want it to change URL when the login is correct, but it just refreshes the page instead.

Comment: try `location.href=url`

Comment: I just tried, even at the start of function UserAction, but nothing happens. I dont think it ever reaches UserAction when pressing submit

Comment: see my answer. its a `from` submit problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use with `return` in `onclick="return UserAction()"` function and add `return false` in end of the 
`UserAction()` function .They will prevent the page refresh .
and `window.location.href=url` is redirect with new page

**Changed JavaScript code**

```
var username;
var password;

function UserAction() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/Footballmanagerrestservice/webresources/login", false);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("", User());
  xhttp.send();
  var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
  console.log(response);
  if (response == "hej") {
      var url = "http://localhost:8080/FM3/spil2.jsp";
      window.location.href=url
}
return false; //added to prevent page refresh
}

function User(user, pass) {
  username = document.getElementById("username").toString();
  username = document.getElementById("password").toString();
  var UserAndPass = "?username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
return UserAndPass;
}
```

**Changed HTML**

```
<div class="login">
        <form method="POST" onsubmit="return UserAction()">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" required><br><br>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: I tried using your way, and added the window.location at the start of the UserAction(), but it still not changing the url. I don't think it's entering the function

Comment: Try my updated answer `onsubmit` event was added and  removed the `click` event from button

Comment: I changed the function to:
function UserAction() {
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/FM3/spil2.jsp";
    window.location.href = url

}
So it should redirect when enter.
But still nothing happen, can i remove "form" and use an onclick on submit?

Comment: If i change the submit to at button, then it will enter the function using onclick="UserAction"

Comment: you are almost done..do with `return false`  in end of `userAction()` .do the old one `function UserAction(){
console.log('sxs')
 location.href="localhost:8080/FM3/spil2.jsp"
 return false;
}`   try this

Answer (score 0):

use `window.location.href = "url_here";` to navigate to new page

Comment: I just tried, even at the start of function UserAction, but nothing happens. I dont think it ever reaches UserAction when pressing submit

Answer (score 0):

Please do a redirect, after checking the user credentials to change the URL

```
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

or simulate clicking a link like

```
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Comment: I just tried, even at the start of function UserAction, but nothing happens. I dont think it ever reaches UserAction when pressing submit

Comment: Then you might be interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384712/capture-a-form-submit-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/FM3/spil2.jsp";
```

Comment: I just tried, even at the start of function UserAction, but nothing happens. I dont think it ever reaches UserAction when pressing submit