# Capture explicit JQuery form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

We have a javascript function which gets called on click of an image in an HTML page. Inside the function, we explicitly submit the form using

```
$('#myForm').get(0).submit();
```

Is there any way for me to capture event of this submit() getting called and then again do a submit after modifying something in the form?

Also, while doing this, I do not know the exact name or id of the form.

Comment: $('#myForm').on("submit", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
//do your actions here//
});

Comment: You can use `$.ajax()`, `FormData` to submit `multipart/form-data` to server

Comment: @thepieterdc, I should edit my question to include this - but can I do this when the form name and id are not known to me?

Comment: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384712/capture-a-form-submit-in-javascript>

Comment: @user8055937 you could try something like ```$("form").on("submit", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); //code here// });```

I am not sure whether this will work but it should capture all submit events on all forms on the HTML page.

Comment: here you can define your submit behavior $.fn.submit = function() { // whatever you want to do } and you call it $(el).submit(). Last example https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: The link posted by @Ursache worked well for my purpose - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384712/capture-a-form-submit-in-javascript%3E - I used the idea of overriding submit method (last post by Vitaliy). What I dont get though is what is the purpose behind the 2 code snippets in that post. Thanks all for the answers.

Comment: Pretty much all the answers here seem to work. The one from @Ursache works best for me - seems to cover all cases. Would like to mark it as correct - seems I need to have more points to do so.