# Display loading icon while file is uploaded

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to show some type of a loading icon when a user uploads a file. I am using a basic  type file upload.

Here is my control code that I am using:

VIEW:

```
  <input type="file" onchange="form.submit()" class="multiple" name="files" id="fileUploadBox"  value="Upload Files"multiple />
```

I have a method in my controller that accepts the file and saves to our database.

You can see that in my code I have onchange="form.submit" which submits the form after the user selects a file. I preferred this way instead of the user having to click another button after selecting the file to submit the form.

My issue is that when the user selects a larger file, the page sits for awhile while loading and uploading the file and then submits the form 20-30 seconds later.

**I am needing to add some code that shows some type of loading/spinning icon while the file is loaded in and the form is resubmitted.**

I believe most of the loading occurs when the file is being uploaded and not during the form submit.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture a form submit in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384712/capture-a-form-submit-in-javascript)

Comment: While your app is processing the form it's data, you could set a boolean to `isLoading = true` and after that, just set it to `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of options and libraries you can use. 
 IF you're using JQuery you can use something like [JQuery Loading Overlay](https://gasparesganga.com/labs/jquery-loading-overlay/) works nicely. There's good documentation there as well.

You'd just change your `onchange` call to something like

```
onchange="submitForm();"
```

and have a javascript function like this for example:

```
function submitForm(){
    $("#spinner").LoadingOverlay("show");
    $("#form").submit();
}
```

There's tonnes of different spinners out there and you don't have to use a JQuery one. But the idea would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bootstrap, i found that you can put text and a spinner. Look at it

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">
  <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"></span>
  Loading..
</button>
```